# How to Access REST Service in Jax-RS using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, rest, curl, jax-rs

I Developed a REST Service in Jax-RS, and I have some functions that use the POST method, like:

1. Auth_User()
2. Get_List()
3. Insert_Data(id,name,data)

I need to access these functions using PHP cURL. What I basically need is to work the functions from the PHP files, so that my REST Service can work like Facebook App development.

how can I do this using cURL?

Comment: It is unclear how you translated the method up there. It would be better if you would put a full scenario explaining what are the interactions between client and servers. in a REST scenario, you do not access functions, you access resources (URIs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CURL](https://www.php.net/curl) library with it's wide range of options to perform GET/POST/HEAD etc. requests that you would need to communicate with your REST server.

As for parsing data, you would have to take a look at either [json_decode](http://at.php.net/json_decode)() if you get json objects back, or e.g. [SimpleXml](http://at.php.net/SimpleXml) if you need to parse it as XML.

See this site here for a decent example of querying the yahoo REST api in php/curl:

http://developer.yahoo.com/php/tutorials/water_bug_tutorial-making_rest_request.html

Comment: can u tell me, i am using auth() for checking the username and password, how can i access that specific function?

Comment: Try something like this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); for basic auth mode.

Comment: but i am using auth() in server for basic auth, without saying that how can i auth my username and pass??

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the server interprets the incoming URI with the supplied username:password combo (hashed as base64 string). If the server interprets that URI in any normal way, it will authenticate. Try it like this: When you manually do a GET request on your REST api by simply using your browser, do you get a dialog asking you for your username and password? If yes, it should work this way.

Comment: Just in case you need it, if you look up CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH on this site: http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php - it lists all possible AUTH modes you can set, which are supported by curl.

Comment: What about other function, i am having JPec() and Th() and i need to work that,both are GET Functions,and arguments for both are $id and $id,$ip respectively,how can i work this two?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a REST server.  The question you are asking is "How do I make an HTTP request from PHP?"  What technology the server is implemented with is absolutely irrelevant.  At least it should be!

Comment: Better than that, I can teach you how to fish.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http+request+php